# Bits do not get shifted when performing shift operation in Verilog

Tags: verilog, spi

I am trying to build an SPI module in verilog which transmits 8 bits of data, but when doing the shift operation I have noticed that shifting does not shift bits at all, while MOSI and MISO only take value of zero after the first cycle, which results in data on both side decaying to zero. What can I do to fix this?

Code for master:

```
module Master(input clk, input MISO, 
              output reg MOSI, output reg SS);
  initial SS = 0;
  reg [2:0] counter;
  reg [7:0] Master_reg = 8'b11011011;
  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      if(!SS)
        begin
          if(^counter === 1'bx)
            counter = 0;
          else
            counter = counter + 1;
          MOSI = Master_reg[7];
          Master_reg = Master_reg >> 1;
          Master_reg[0] = MISO;
        end
      if(counter == 7)
          SS = 1; 
    end
endmodule
```

Code for slave:

```
module Slave(input clk, input MOSI, input SS,
            output reg MISO);
  reg [2:0] counter;
  reg [7:0] Slave_reg = 8'b11111111;
  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      if(!SS)
        begin
          if(^counter === 1'bx)
            counter = 0;
          else
            counter = counter + 1;
          MISO = Slave_reg[0];
          Slave_reg = Slave_reg << 1;
          Slave_reg[7] = MOSI;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Transmission of given data (11011011 from master, 11111111 from slave) gives following result:
[image: output]

Edit: I am using [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/home) as a simulator

Comment: Inside an `always @ (posedge clk)` you should use non-blocking assignments. These : `<=` (You realise that this: `(^counter === 1'bx)` can not be synthesized...)

Comment: @Oldfart I have tried non-blocking assignments and they produce same output. For the time being I just want the simulation to work, so I disregarded synthesizeability of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mistake in both master and slave. You're sending out the most significant bit of `master_reg`, but shifting that register to the right. You must shift it left instead.

Same with slave, the bit that's being sent is not the one toward which the data is shifted.

Btw, both the master and slave must shift to the same direction. Otherwise you'll get data reversed between master and slave.

Comment: You are not answering his question. Yes, the code is very.... (How do I say this politely....) "sub-optimal" but that is not the issue here.

Comment: @Vlad, I tired your suggestion (flipped shifts on m&s sides) and that did work, (although bits are reversed) but I am very confused: doesnt `register << 1;` operation shift bits to the left? If so shouldnt register[7] always be zero in such case?

Comment: @Ach113 both, master and slave must shift its data in the same direction. If you go with MSB being sent first, both master and slave must output reg[7], shift data to the left, and save input data in reg[0]. You have it reversed because your master and slave will shift in different directions.

Comment: @Vlad, thanks the code works now. But still cannot wrap my head around why shifting to left and then sending rightmost bit does not always send a zero.

Comment: @Ach113 There's always correct initial value, so the first bit sent would be ok. Problem is when you're shifting away from the line corresponding to device output. Your MOSI was at the MSB, reg[7]. And the rest of the data was on the right of that bit. So in order to get that data out, you must shift it towards the reg[7], i.e. to the left.

Comment: additionally to the logic fix, in order to prevent possible issues, use non-blocking assignments in posedged always blocks for all outputs (as oldfat suggested). Also get rid of triple '=' if you plan to synthesize it.